# Segmentation Code when inputting higher values

Tags: c++

So I created a c++ code that counts "special" numbers in a given range, which is defined as a number where the total of its number of 1-bits in its binary representation is less than our equal to 3 (i.e. 1(1), 2(10), 3(11), 4(100), 5(101), 6(110), 7(111), 8(1000).

I successfully created the code, however there is one problem. At high number ranges, it outputs segmentation fault.

Any idea as to why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

long special(long x, long y){
    long sArray[y];
    long output = 0;

    sArray[0]=0;
    sArray[1]=1;

    for(long i = 2; i<=y; i++){
        long j = floor(i/2);
        sArray[i] = sArray[j]+(i%2);
        if (i>=x && sArray[i]<=3){
            output++;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<special(5,2717261);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sArray[y]` is out of bounds access. And C++ doesn't allow Variadic Length Arrays.

Comment: Why does `special` take two arguments? What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: x and y are the ranges where x is the lower bound and y is the higher bound

Comment: `long sArray[y];` is not legal C++. Learn about `std::vector`.

Comment: c++ doesnt allow variadic length arrays? maybe I should use malloc instead?

Comment: No you should not use malloc. You should use std::vector.

Comment: okay! I got it to work. Thank you everyone for your help. It seems using std::vector solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault occurs because you try to declare an array that's too large and extends outside the current memory segment.

Frankly, you don't need this array, and can just count the number of special numbers in the given range:

```
boolean isSpecial(long num) {
   int bits = 0;
   while (num > 0) {
       if (num % 2 > 0) {
           ++bits;
           if (bits >= 3) {
               return true;
           }
       }
       num /= 2;
   }
   return false;
}

long special(long x, long y) {
    long output = 0;
    for(long i = x; i <= y; ++i) {
        if (isSpecial(i)) {
            ++output;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```